# c++ std::format from <format> module crashes the program

Tags: module, crash, std, c++20, stdformat

I have a simple program in `main.cpp` file:

```
import <iostream>;
import <format>;

int main() {
  std::cout << std::format("{}, {}!", "Hello", "world") << std::endl;
}
```

It uses `iostream` and `format` modules which are compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header iostream
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header format
```

I compile the program with

```
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts main.cpp
```

then launch it - and it just hangs for a few seconds then the process stops without printing anything.

I compile and run it on Windows with MinGW g++ 13.1.0. After each crash a new report appears in the Reliability Monitor with exception code "c0000005". If I don't use this `std::format` function then no crash happens (the program still has `import <format>;` line).

Is it a bug in the standard library or do I compile something wrong? Can it be fixed somehow?